# compress image file from camera to certain size

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, android-bitmap

I'm trying to compress an image that I saved in the file. I'm trying to compress the File into 1MB. I try a few way but it usually make an OutofMemoryError.
and then i tried to use this solution, but it makes the bitmap blank.

> [How to compress bitmap from 10mb image from camera to 300kb beforw setting to imageview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415478/how-to-compress-bitmap-from-10mb-image-from-camera-to-300kb-beforw-setting-to-im)

Here is my code :

```
    System.gc();
    getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(mImageTempUri, null);
    Bitmap bitmap;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageDirectory + mImageName, options);
    if(bitmap == null){
    howRequestFailedErrorMessage("Gambar gagal di-upload");
    return;

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   


    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, bytes);
    File f = new File(mImageDirectory + mImageName);
    if(f.exists()){
        f.delete();
    }
    FileOutputStream fo;

    try {
        fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.flush();
        fo.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bitmap.recycle();
```

Comment: Did you try to put compressed  data to fileOutputStream directly?  You create two sets of  jpeg image data, one is in ByteArrayOutputStream explicitly, and  the other is bytes.toBytesArray temporarily. I guess these data may cause 'Out of memory' error.  You may be able to avoid these data by the code "bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, fo);"

Comment: @Fumu7 I don't really get it, can u give the example in code? actually out of memory is not really the issue right now, the main problem is that I can't compress the image dynamically, and I have to adjust the quality staticly (which is 25 now)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

okay, I got my own answer

```
    File f = new File(mImageDirectory + mImageName);
    if(f.exists()){
        f.delete();
    }

    int MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 1000 * 1024;
    int streamLength = MAX_IMAGE_SIZE;
    int compressQuality = 105;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bmpStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while (streamLength >= MAX_IMAGE_SIZE && compressQuality > 5) {
        try {
            bmpStream.flush();//to avoid out of memory error
            bmpStream.reset();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        compressQuality -= 5;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressQuality, bmpStream);
        byte[] bmpPicByteArray = bmpStream.toByteArray();
        streamLength = bmpPicByteArray.length;
        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.d("test upload", "Quality: " + compressQuality);
            Log.d("test upload", "Size: " + streamLength);
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream fo;

    try {
        fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bmpStream.toByteArray());
        fo.flush();
        fo.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: you may check size without creating byte[], just get bmpStream.size()
`mBitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, percentDecompression, outputStream);
                actualSize = outputStream.size();`

Answer (score 3):

> Kotlin Way

```
        if (file.length() > MAX_IMAGE_SIZE) {
            var streamLength = MAX_IMAGE_SIZE
            var compressQuality = 105
            val bmpStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            while (streamLength >= MAX_IMAGE_SIZE && compressQuality > 5) {
                bmpStream.use {
                    it.flush()
                    it.reset()
                }

                compressQuality -= 5
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath, BitmapFactory.Options())
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressQuality, bmpStream)
                val bmpPicByteArray = bmpStream.toByteArray()
                streamLength = bmpPicByteArray.size
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    Log.d("test upload", "Quality: $compressQuality")
                    Log.d("test upload", "Size: $streamLength")
                }
            }

            FileOutputStream(file).use {
                it.write(bmpStream.toByteArray())
            }
        }
```

> Constant

```
companion object {
    //2000 * 1024 = 2 MB
    private const val MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 2048000
}
```